# simple rest api server to pass arguments to a shell script and execute it on shell

Tags: ruby, perl, api, sed, cgi

I simply want to have a rest api server which I can call to update a file via a URL, that's it.

Here is the file:

```
mytextfile:
       key1 = value1
       key2 = value2
```

1. On the client, a script will be run which sends a string or strings to the API server.
2. The API server will receive them, for example `/update.script?string1="blah"&string2="fun"` (pretend its url encoded)
3. The server should then parse these strings, and then call an exec function, or another script even on the system which does some sed command to update a file

Language or implementation doesn't matter.

Looking for fresh ideas.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with a "form based" solution? Your example request is identical to the one that a form with `string1` and `string2` input elements would generate.

Comment: Because I don't want a visible page.

Comment: I see the vote down must have come from the Node/Ruby community. Removing tag for the hipster lemmings.

Comment: You don't have to *display* a page to pass form input!

Comment: Hipster lemmings? Unbelievable. On Stack Overflow, it is preferred that the question poster puts some effort into formulating a great question instead of trying to insult the people who provide help for free. Voting -1 "This question does not show any research effort" ([Do your homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)); voting to close as "not a real question"/"This question is … incomplete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a newer Perl framework, like [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us). If I make a file (`test.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'file.txt';

any '/' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my @params = $self->param;

  my $data = do $file;
  $data->{$_} = $self->param($_) for @params;

  open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Cannot open $file";

  local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
  print $fh Dumper $data;

  $self->render( text => "File Updated\n" );
};

app->start;
```

Then run `morbo test.pl`

and visit `http://localhost:3000/?hello=world` (or run `./test.pl get /?hello=world`)

then I get in `file.txt`:

```
{
  'hello' => 'world'
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get it: What exactly is your problem/question?

My approach to the problem *"modifying a file from inside a cgi script using url-encoded arguments"* would be:

1. Pick a language you like and start coding, in my case with Perl.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use strict; use warnings;
   ```
2. Fetch all your arguments. I will use the [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.60/lib/CGI.pm) module of Perl here:

   ```
   use CGI::Carp;
   use CGI;
   my $cgi = CGI->new;

   # assuming we don't have multivalued fields:
   my %arguments = $cgi->Values; # handles (almost) *all* decoding and splitting
   # validate arguments
   # send back CGI header to acknowledge the request
   # the server will make a HTTP header from that
   ```
3. Now either call a special subroutine / function with them …

   ```
   updateHandler(%arguments);
   ...;
   my $filename = 'path to yer file name.txt';
   sub updateHandler {
      my %arguments = @_;
      # open yer file, loop over yer arguments, whatever

      # read in file
      open my $fileIn, '<', $filename or die "Can't open file for reading";
      my @lines = <$fileIn>;
      close $fileIn;

      # open the file for writing, completely ignoring concurrency issues:
      open my $fileOut, '>', $filename or die "Can't open file for writing";

      # loop over all lines, make substitutions, and print it out
      foreach my $line (@lines) {
         # assuming a file format with key-value pairs
         # keys start at the first column
         # and are seperated from values by an '=',
         # surrounded by any number of whitespace characters
         my ($key, $value) = split /\s*=\s*/, $line, 2;

         $value = $arguments{$key} // $value;
         # you might want to make sure $value ends with a newline

         print $fileOut $key, " = ", $value;
      }
   }
   ```

   Please *don't use* this rather insecure and suboptimal code! I just wrote this as a demonstration that this isn't really complicated.
4. … or contrieve a way to send your arguments to another script (although Perl is more than well suited for file manipulation tasks). Choose one of the `qw{}`, `system` or `exec` commands, depending on what output you need from your script, or decide to pipe your arguments to the script using the `open my $fh, '|-', $command` mode of `open`.
5. As for the server to run this script on: Apache looks fine to me, unless you have very special needs (your own protocol, single-threading, low security, low performance) in which case you might want to code your own server. Using the [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Daemon-6.01/lib/HTTP/Daemon.pm) module you might manage <50 lines for a simplicistic server.

   When using Apache, I'd strongly suggest using mod_rewrite to put the `/path` into the `PATH_INFO` environment variable. When using one script to represent your whole REST API, you could use the `PATH_INFO` to choose one of many methods/subroutines/functions. This also eliminates the need to name the script in the URL.

   For example, turn the URL

   ```
   http://example.com/rest/modify/filename?key1=value1
   ```

   into

   ```
   /cgi-bin/rest-handler.pl/modify/filename?key1=value1
   ```

   Inside the Perl script, we would then have `$ENV{PATH_INFO}` containing `/modify/filename`.

This is a bit Perl-centric, but just pick *any* language you are comfortable with and start coding, leveraging whatever module you can use on the way.